# How to send API request using java script?I'm following the below code , but i'm not able to display it can you suggest me the code?

Tags: getjson

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $.getJSON(stg.api.bazaarvoice.com/data/reviews.json?apiversion=5.4&passkey=ywwm6ry3sw5r4ak9j7f2x9ed&filter=productid:<?php echo $product?>&stats=reviews 
    function(json){var output = json);
    $("#BVRReview").append(output);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle with your code in so we can analyse your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/89a3a3fa/) is a JSFiddle that demonstrates how you can retrieve data from your API using a jQuery AJAX request.

It will output the `AuthorId` and `ReviewText` into a div for demonstration purposes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://stg.api.bazaarvoice.com/data/reviews.json?apiversion=5.4&passkey=ywwm6ry3sw5r4ak9j7f2x9ed",
    data: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      for (i in data['Results']){
        var info = data['Results'][i];
        $('.results').append(info.AuthorId + "</br>" + info.ReviewText + "</br></br>");
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: what is "Result" in data['Results'] and $('.results')?

Comment: Go and look at the JSFiddle. Data['results']  is the results object within the data object, returned by the API.

Comment: $('.results') relates to the Div element in the JSFiddle