# How to make an API call to get the reviews in bazaarvoice extension?reviews.phtml code is mentioned below

Tags: getjson

```
<?php if ($this->getIsEnabled()):?>
    <?php $doShowContentJs = Mage::getStoreConfig('bazaarvoice/rr/do_show_content_js');
    $seoContent = $this->getSEOContent();
    ?>
    <div id="BVRRContainer">
    <?php echo $seoContent ?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $BV.ui( 'rr', 'show_reviews', {
    doShowContent : function () {
      <?php echo $doShowContentJs ?>
    }
    });    
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Your code got hidden due to improper formatting. I've edited for you.Accept the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794439/how-to-send-api-request-using-java-scriptim-following-the-below-code-but-im/) answer here provides an example of how to retrieve the reviews, but I'll provide a snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://stg.api.bazaarvoice.com/data/reviews.json?apiversion=5.4&passkey=***ENTER PASSKEY HERE***&filter=productid:***PRODUCTID***",
    data: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      for (i in data['Results']){
        var info = data['Results'][i];
        console.log(info.AuthorId + " || " + info.ReviewText);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: is this for a particulat product .We are not providing any filter here then how can it fetch the details of our product

Comment: Look at the API documentation. Howeever, I've added in a filter parameter to the URL. All you need to do is specify the product ID.

Comment: I have seen the documentation if I'm passing the below url I'm not able to get the output. URL:http://stg.api.bazaarvoice.com/data/reviews.json?apiversion=5.4&include=products,authors&Filter=ProductId:C1&filter=isRatingsOnly:false&filter=DisplayLocale:en_US&passkey=ywwm6ry3sw5r4ak9j7f2x9ed&limit=5

Comment: and I'm sending the reviews for that product to submitreview through another ajax call .May I know the relationship between submitreview.json and reviews.json?How they are related

Comment: You're not able to get the output because there is no output. There are no products/reviews or whatever matching all of your parameters. I don't know the relationship, I don't know that API thoroughly.

Comment: There is no `ProductID:C1`.

Comment: thanks for your answers but the problem is I have posted the reviews to submitreview.json file and I'm retrieving it throught reviews.json.Do you have best way to post and get reviews to bazaarvoice through API?